# python listについての質問

Tags: python

pythonを始めたての初心者です。

```py
list=['a','i','u','e','o']
list[1:4]=['a']
```

とした場合

```py
['a','a','a','e','o']
```

となると思ったのですが

```py
['a','a','o']
```

長さが短くなってしまいました。
何が違うのかご教示いただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: 上記コードは実行すると「SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier」となります。質問者さんが実際に実行したコードを載せてもらいたいです。

Comment: 参考までに、想定通りの結果を得るには `lst[0:3] = ['a']*len(lst[0:3])` とします(意味のない書き方ですが)。また、Python ではリスト(sequence type)の index は `0` から始まります(`0-base index`)。

Answer (score 0):

Pythonでの listは, 他の言語では dynamic-array などと呼ばれるものです
動的にサイズが変動するので, 質問にある動作が普通の動作です
参考:
[データ構造:リスト型について](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

長さを固定にする場合は, そのようなデータ構造を選んで使用することになります

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e'])
arr[1:4] = 'a'

# array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'e'], dtype='<U1')
```

標準パッケージだと, (もしかすると) `array` で可能かもしれない

---

あと `list` や `dict` など, Pythonの基本データ型と同じ名前は使用しないほうがよいでしょう
(使うならたとえば `lst` `dct` など, 違うものに)

Answer (score 0):

スライスへの割り当てを行うとリストの長さは変わってしまいます。

https://docs.python.org/ja/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range
リファレンスによると
s[i:j] = t
s の i から j 番目までのスライスをイテラブル t の内容に入れ替えます

"入れ替える"と記載されています。

Comment: 「 i から j までのスライス」であって, 「 j 番目」ではありません。(jは含まない)
(スライスでなければ, `s[j]` を `j`番目と表現するのは妥当だけど)

Answer (score 0):

ちなみに周りくどく書き換えるならこのように書いたらいいと思われます。

```
lis = ['a', 'i', 'u', 'e', 'o']
del lis[1:3]
lis.insert(1, 'a')
lis.insert(2, 'a')
lis
```